# DataTables - Process rows with specific cell class

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm attempting to loop through a DataTable, and only process rows that contain a cell with a class of "success". I'm having trouble getting the syntax properly; can anyone assist?

Here's what I have so far (that isn't working):

```
for(i=0; i<myDataTable.rows()[0].length; i++) {
    if(myDataTable.rows(i).data()[0] != "" && myDataTable.rows(i).data()[0].child('td').hasClass('success')) {
        <process stuff>
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `myDataTable` look like?

Comment: Please tell us what database you use because we have no idea.

Comment: @amflare I don't think that's really relevant? I'm just trying to identify if any <td> within row(i) has a class of "success". Everything else works fine, and I'm just trying to constrain my if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [`row().node()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().node()) DataTables API call in combination with the `.find()` jQuery function:

```
for(i=0; i<myDataTable.rows()[0].length; i++) {
    if(myDataTable.row(i).data()[0] != "" // <-- See Note about this part 
      && $(myDataTable.row(i).node()).find('td.success').length) {
        //process stuff
    }
}
```

This modification of your code snippet will use the `node()` call, which gets the `<tr>` element of the row found by `myDataTable.row(i)`. Then, we can use the `find()` method to check if **any** (it would be different if you only cared about a specific column) of the `<td>` in that `<tr>` have the `success` class.

**Note**

Your code has `myDataTable.row(i).data()[0] != ""`. This checks that the first column of the row is not the empty string. If you want that to be part of the condition for processing, leave it in, but I'm not sure since you didn't mention that in the question.

Also note that for a single row, you should use `row()` not `rows()`.

Comment: For whatever reason, I have to make that node into a jQuery object. So, `&& $(myDataTable.row(i).node()).find('td.success').length` did the trick for me.

Comment: @niclake Oh, yeah that's my bad. I'll fix it in the example for future readers. Nice catch!

Comment: Also of note... you removed the [0] from the original `i<myDataTable.rows()[0].length;`, and that needs to remain. Otherwise the length will return 1, instead of the count of rows within the array.

Comment: @niclake I'll fix that as well.